# Is it possible to to re-serialize parsed TCPDF data back into PDF form?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to examine the contents of a PDF file like so:

```
$file_content = file_get_contents("path_to_file.pdf");
$parser = new TCPDF_PARSER($file_content);
$data = $parser->getParsedData();
$some_value = $data[1]["8_0"][0][1][31][1];
```

I would like to be able to modify the data in PHP array form, and then re-serialize that modified data back into a PDF, something like:

```
$data[1]["8_0"][0][1][31][1] = "Modified data";
$re_serialized = hypothetical_reserialize_function($data);
file_put_contents("modified.pdf", $re_serialized);
```

Is this possible to do? Unfortunately it seems like a large amount of the documentation for TCPDF is no longer online. I'd like to not be working in PHP, but I'm stuck with it for this problem.

Saving the $data object to a file obviously does not work, and the TCPDF constructor (`new TCPDF();`) does not seem to support passing a parsed object as a parameter.

Comment: I believe you would have to completely recreate the PDF